# discord.js paladins bot tracker embed

Tags: node.js, discord.js

i am trying to make paladins stat bot..i got the session and the respond in console.log...but how do i get the value from that console to embed in discord..i cant get the value of that..

```
                var platform=args[1].toUpperCase();
                var player=args[2];
                var sessionId;
                pal.connect('PC', (err, res) => {
                if(!err) {
                    sessionId = res;
                }


              pal.getPlayer(sessionId, platform,player,(err,res) => {
                   if(!err)

                   var data=res;
               // var created=data.value(Created_Datetime);

                    var embed=new Discord.RichEmbed()
                    .setAuthor(data.Name)
                    .addField("created", data.Created_Datetime)
                    message.channel.sendMessage(embed);

                    console.log(data);
            });
        });
```

this is the code i wrote...i got the result in console..

```
    Created_Datetime: '2/13/2017 2:35:18 PM',
    Id: 7221980,
    Last_Login_Datetime: '4/14/2018 4:57:36 PM',
    Leaves: 37,
    Level: 266,
    Losses: 1667,
    MasteryLevel: 36,
    Name: 'HEIMDALL2304',
    Personal_Status_Message: '',
    RankedConquest:
     { Leaves: 4,
       Losses: 23,
       Name: 'Conquest',
       Points: 0,
       PrevRank: 0,
       Rank: 0,
       Rank_Stat_Conquest: null,
       Rank_Stat_Duel: null,
       Rank_Stat_Joust: null,
       Season: 2,
       Tier: 15,
       Trend: 0,
       Wins: 24,
       player_id: null,
       ret_msg: null },
    Region: 'Southeast Asia',
    TeamId: 0,
    Team_Name: '',
    Tier_Conquest: 15,
    Total_Achievements: 54,
    Total_Worshippers: 239779435,
    Wins: 1734,
    ret_msg: null } ]
```

[console data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6ONw.png)

How do i embed it i.e put this individual value from data to embed using RichEmbed() ?
I am getting undefined with each field..what's wrong ? help me solve this..i need to complete this project..

```
[9:50 PM] shin5an: ^paladins pc heimdall2304
[9:50 PM] BOT ALU:
                   created
                   undefined
```

[embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdmGh.png)

Comment: Post the link for the picture, we can add it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Xzandro said above the output is an array so `data[0].Name` and `data[0].Created_Datetime` should work well.
Just use the . Operator for further nesting if needed.
For eg to access the wins in Ranked Conquest do `data[0].RankedConquest.Wins`

Undefined just means that you are not pointing to a valid variable key as of yet. So try the above and let us know if it works.

Comment: But can u please explain me..as this is a array ..why data[0] everytime for each stat...why not data[0] for one value and data[1] for the next and so on...?it gives me error if i use the later case..0,1...

Comment: Because you are send specific user id as arguments ... As a result there is only one data element of the specific user(array has only 1 element)... And hence only data[0]

Comment: If this solved your problem please mark this as your answer by click on the tick next to this answer ... Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems that the data is an array, did you try `data[0].Created_Datetime`?

Comment: data[0],Created_Datetime ...it works ...perfect... thanks